# Using magento2 Soap api in .NET

Tags: magento2, c#

I am trying to consume magento2 soap api in .NET C#, and can find that to consume sales api's we need to be authorize, i have the authorization token , but can anybody help me how we can add this in .net as service reference,

http://magento2url/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1

I am getting "consumer not authorize" as error.